# Is arg(f(z)) continuous when f is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, polar-coordinates

My question is same with the title.

When f(z) is analytic(or just continuous), arg(f) is differentiable(or just continuous)?

If not, what restrictions are needed for arg(f) to be continuous?

Thanks!

Comment: If $U$ is a simply connected domain and $f$ is analytic on $U$ and has no zero then there is an analytic function $g$ such that $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$. Proof : $g'(z )= f'(z)/f(z)$ is analytic thus so is $g(z) = \log f(a)+ \int_a^z g'(s)ds$

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to ask whether arg(f) is continuous, since arg(f) is not even uniquely defined.

Comment: f’/f is analytic on simply connected domain U. Thus f’/f has an antiderivative g. So g’ = f’/f. And I don’t get it how I can get the last equation and how the conclusion follows from it.

Comment: If I get the conclusion, just put g(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)? Then arg(f(z)) = v(x,y) and v is continuous?

Comment: If we restrict the arg function to have values between α and α+2π, does it make sense?

Comment: On a simply connected domain that does not contain zero, arg(z) can have (α,α+2π) as a codomain.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$\operatorname{Arg}(z)$, if defined in any sensible way on all of $\Bbb C$, isn't continuous, no matter how you slice it.

If $f(z)$ is continuous and never zero, $\operatorname{Arg}(f(z))$ can be continuous. There are two ways to make this work:

1. If there is some continuous, non-self-intersecting curve from the origin to $\infty$ that $f(z)$ never hits, you can use that as the branch cut for $\operatorname{Arg}$, and everything works nicely.
2. Accept the multivalued nature of $\operatorname{Arg}$, and let $\operatorname{Arg}(f(z))$ be multivalued as well. Then it's not strictly speaking a function, but *locally* it behaves like a function.

In either case, it is continuous. An $\varepsilon$-ball around $\operatorname{Arg}(f(z))$ corresponds to a sector around $f(z)$ in $\Bbb C$. And assuming $f$ is continuous and $f(z)\neq0$, you can always find a $\delta$-ball around $z$ which, when mapped with $f$, lands inside this sector.

Comment: Oh! How can I show that its argument is continuous when it is never zero?

Comment: @anadad Standard $\epsilon$-$\delta$ ought to do the trick. Alternately, $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is continuous anywhere else, and composition is continuous.

Comment: If you take $f(z) = z$ on the punctured complex plane, your two sentences seem to contradict each other.

Comment: Should I think it geometrically? I drew a δ-ball around a non-zero point and try to find the relation between δ and the maximum argument between a point in the ball and the non-zero point. But I don’t have an idea yet.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as on domains that are not simply connected it may not be possible to define the argument continuously even if the function is non zero ($z$ on the punctured unit disc). On a simply connected domain the argument of an analytic function that is never zero can be defined uniquely if one fixes the value at a point and then it is harmonic hence infinitely differentiable and more - the standard choice is to fix it as zero at a fixed real value of the function; the proof is noting that it is the imaginary part of the analytic function $\log f$

Comment: @Conrad I am aware. I have updated my answer (even before you posted your comment). I believe that edit addressed most of your concerns.

Comment: It is actually not that hard to show that you can define $\log f$ as a continuos function for any continuos function that is never zero on a simply connected domain and then the argument is just the imaginary part of that and is continuos

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now :)